# Dynamic Table HTML, ADD and Delete

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am currently developing a table in html for data processing where the values ​​are passed to the database through this table. Thus, the table needs to be dynamic. I was able to develop the addition part in the table but I am already more than a day trying to delete a row from the table and the most I could do was delete the  "thead", the goal is that in each row an additional cell is created to delete the row itself . The code is currently like this.

HTML:

```
<table border="4">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Exercicio</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="userExercise" id="userExercise"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Membro</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="userMember" id="userMember"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Repetições</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="userRep" id="userRep"></td>
                </tr>
              
                
                
                <tr id="btna">
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="button" name="button" id="btn" value="Add" onclick="AddRow()"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table border="4" id="show">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Exercício</th>
                    <th>Membro</th>
                    <th>Repetições</th>
                    <th>Deletar</th>
                
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

javascript:

```
var list1 = [];

var list2 = [];

var list3 = [];

var list4 = [];

        var n = 1;
        var x = 0;

        function AddRow(){

            var AddRown = document.getElementById('show');
            var NewRow = AddRown.insertRow(n);

            list1[x] = document.getElementById("userExercise").value;
            list2[x] = document.getElementById("userMember").value;
            list3[x] = document.getElementById("userRep").value;
            list4[x] = "Deleta"

            

            var cel1 = NewRow.insertCell(0);
            var cel2 = NewRow.insertCell(1);
            var cel3 = NewRow.insertCell(2);
            var cel4 = NewRow.insertCell(3);

    

            cel1.innerHTML = list1[x];
            cel2.innerHTML = list2[x];
            cel3.innerHTML = list3[x];
            cel4.innerHTML = list4[x];
            
            console.log(show.rows.length)
    

            n++;
            x++;
        }

      

            var index, table = document.getElementById('show');
            for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
            {
                table.rows[i].cells[3].onclick = function()
                {
                    var c = confirm("do you want to delete this row");
                    if(c === true)
                    {
                        index = this.parentElement.rowIndex;
                        table.deleteRow(index);
                    }
                    
                    console.log(index);
                };
                
            }
```

Well, when I click "Delete", nothing happens and when I change the initial value of "i" in for (var i = 1; i <table.rows.length; i ++) to try to delete the header, the function works, someone could you give any hint of where I may be going wrong?

I added an image to the post to assist in viewing

[Result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hJwq.png)

Comment: First, you  need to get the element from the click event, in order to know what cell was clicked and what row is the parent that you need to delete.  After you have that working, you might want to look at delegates, so you don't need to assign an onclick event to each cell, but rather to the whole table.  The documentation on delegate handling will show you what element, the cell, was clicked so you still have that information to work with when you delete to row.

Comment: You say that you're building the table dynamically, in javascript or on a server when you create the page.  The issue is that simple posting won't send the whole table, only input fields.  Unless you resort to some ajax call and package your table into  some combinable format, your table data won't generally be seen by your server to be placed in your database.  If you're updating the database from your javascript then this last part isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version.

I removed the 2nd `for` loop and included setting the `onclick` to the delete into the insert of a new row.

The issue with your version, is the 2nd `for` loop that sets the `onclick` only happens on page load and at that stage there is only the table header. By putting the `onclick` into the `AddRow` function, it is applied each time, as necessary.

```js
var list1 = [];
var list2 = [];
var list3 = [];
var list4 = [];

        var n = 1;
        var x = 0;

        function AddRow(){

            var AddRown = document.getElementById('show');
            var NewRow = AddRown.insertRow(n);

            list1[x] = document.getElementById("userExercise").value;
            list2[x] = document.getElementById("userMember").value;
            list3[x] = document.getElementById("userRep").value;
            list4[x] = "Deleta"

            var cel1 = NewRow.insertCell(0);
            var cel2 = NewRow.insertCell(1);
            var cel3 = NewRow.insertCell(2);
            var cel4 = NewRow.insertCell(3);

            cel1.innerHTML = list1[x];
            cel2.innerHTML = list2[x];
            cel3.innerHTML = list3[x];
            cel4.innerHTML = list4[x];
            cel4.onclick = function()
                {
                    var c = confirm("do you want to delete this row");
                    if(c === true)
                    {
                        index = this.parentElement.rowIndex;
                        var AddRown = document.getElementById('show');
                        AddRown.deleteRow(index);
                        n--;
                        x--;
                    }
                    
                    console.log(index);
                };
            
            console.log(show.rows.length)
    

            n++;
            x++;
        }
```

```html
<table border="4">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Exercicio</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="userExercise" id="userExercise"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Membro</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="userMember" id="userMember"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Repetições</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="userRep" id="userRep"></td>
                </tr>
              
                
                
                <tr id="btna">
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="button" name="button" id="btn" value="Add" onclick="AddRow()"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table border="4" id="show">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Exercício</th>
                    <th>Membro</th>
                    <th>Repetições</th>
                    <th>Deletar</th>
                
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, I followed the StewartR's and Symfony-Wonderer's tip and the code is fully functional now, thanks.